# Remove parent element with Javascript using parentNode.removeChild when I only have 1 parent?

Tags: javascript, removechild, parent-node

I'm working on a project where I have to delete en element in a certain condition (if). My code generates a `<li>` in which data is inserted via an array. I need to delete that `<li>` if some conditions are met.

Since `removeParent()` doesn't exist I've found different methods saying to use

```
e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
```

Rings a bell, it works in certains cases of course.

BUT

In my case, this is dynamically rendered elements in an array inside the `<li>` and there is no parent of the parent, so I get an error.
My script looks for an element in the `<li>`, in my test I use a `<div>` found by its class.

```
$(node).find('.results-name')[0].parentNode.remove();
```

Does NOT work unfortunately so I'm looking for other ideas...

Any clue?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: looks like a mix of native js and jquery - if you are using jquery, why not just do `$('.results-name').parent().remove();`

Comment: @Pete I've tried that but it doesn't work as I would need to remove only the current parent and not all of the items :/

I've tried mixing with $(node).find('.results-name')[0].parent().remove(); but it won't work ...

Comment: ok but you can use jquery? Have you tried without the `[0]`: `$(node).find('.results-name').parent().remove();`

Comment: @Pete yes if I insert `$('.results-name').parent().remove();` it removes all the results

Comment: check my above comment again

Comment: If I don't use the [0] the script doesn't search for the current result item its populating so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The issue comes from the fact that the parent I want to remove is outside the loop where the javascript populates the page using the template.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the code is huge and I can't copy/paste everything here.

Here's more info:
- in the page I have a template that's used by the javascript to populate a div with all the contents. I have ~20 results.
The template starts like this :

```
<script id="itemtemplate" type="geowacht/template">
    <div class="results-name">
        <h4 class="show-more-name itemaponaam" data-target="#result"></h4>
            <div class="d-block" id="result">
            <div class="itemaddress"></div>
            <div class="itemgeodesc"></div>
            <div class="itemphone"></div>
```

- The pages calls a script that queries an API and returns 20 results. These results are parsed and added to the page using the template.
  Here's the beginning of the code:

`apiconfig.default_populateItemNode = function(node, apotheekData, wachtPeriodeData, authenticationData) {
$(node).find('.itemaponaam')[0].setAttribute('data-target', '#result-' + itemPos);
    $(node).find('.buttons')[0].setAttribute('id', 'result-' + itemPos + '-buttons');
    $(node).find('.buttons')[0].setAttribute('data-apbnb', apotheekData.pharmacy.id);`